# Async/await to lookup document IDs and then look up separate document set

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I record favorite offers that a user 'hearts' in my app . These records include the owner and offer IDs. I want to collect the top 25 favorited Offers for a particular user. All firestore commands are asynchronous and I need to collect all the offer objects before I render the page.

Its my first time using async / await and what started as one has quickly grown into nested async / awaits. There must be a simpler way to collect the IDs from the fav objects and then lookup the Offers with those IDs?

```
        async getItems() {
          const collectfavs = async () => {
            favsRef = firestore.collection('favs').where('owner','==',getUserID()).orderBy('created', 'desc').limit(25);
            let allFavsSnapshot = await favsRef.get();
            allFavsSnapshot.forEach(doc => {
                let data = doc.data();
                favsList.push(data.offer);
            });
            console.log('favs:',favsList);
          }
          const collectoffers = async () => {
            favsList.forEach(async (fav) => {
                let doc = await firestore.collection('offers').doc(fav).get()
                console.log('doc:', doc);

                let data = doc.data();
                data.id = doc.id;
                offerList.push(data);
            });
            console.log('offers:', offerList);
          }
          await collectfavs();
          await collectoffers();
       }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up needing to create my own asyncForEach routine to accommodate the async calls to firebase inside the loop. Thanks to an article by Sebastien Chopin [asyncForEach](https://codeburst.io/javascript-async-await-with-foreach-b6ba62bbf404)

```
async function asyncForEach(array, callback) {
  for (let index = 0; index < array.length; index++) {
    await callback(array[index], index, array);
  }
}
```

and then in my getItems:

```
await asyncForEach(favsList, async (fav) => {
        let doc = await firestore.collection('offers').doc(fav).get()
        let data = doc.data();
        data.id = doc.id;
        offerList.push(data);
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why you're defining two local functions just to call them each once.  That seems like more code than necessary to get the job done.  Other than that, what you're doing doesn't seem very complex to me.  But if you want to reduce the lines of code:

```
    async getItems() {
        favsRef = firestore.collection('favs').where('owner','==',getUserID()).orderBy('created', 'desc').limit(25);
        let allFavsSnapshot = await favsRef.get();
        allFavsSnapshot.forEach(doc => {
            let data = doc.data();
            favsList.push(data.offer);
        });
        console.log('favs:',favsList);

        favsList.forEach(async (fav) => {
            let doc = await firestore.collection('offers').doc(fav).get()
            console.log('doc:', doc);

            let data = doc.data();
            data.id = doc.id;
            offerList.push(data);
        });
        console.log('offers:', offerList);
   }
```

Bear in mind that I have no idea where you defined `favsList` and `offerList`, so I'm just blindly using it the same way you showed.

Comment: Your solution printed favs, offers, doc, doc to the console ... which means the offerList was empty when I used it on the page instead of being filled beforehand.

Comment: I've added the solution which was to write my own asyncForEach to wait for each Firebase promise to complete. Tricky.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand from your comment to Doug Stevenson above you want to ensure that you lists will be filled before using them. In order to do that you could you [Promises](https://developer.ibm.com/articles/promises-in-nodejs-an-alternative-to-callbacks/). What Promises do is give us a way to deal with asynchrony in the code in a sequential manner.

All you need to do is create a promise that will ensure that you first fill the Lists you want and then you use them.

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: It seems that Firebase uses promises a lot since every call is asynchronous. That helps when I nest various firebase/firestore functions to add or update a datastore object. It also seems that in JS that people are moving more toward async/await for handling asynchronous calls. In this case I would like to use async/await for gathering up the list of datastore objects before rendering the page.